# CentOS 7 Kernel Update

Tags: centos, kernel

I updated the kernel on our servers from the CentOS default of 3.10.xxx to 4.17.xxx using the elrepo repository.

After adding the repo, I installed the kernel-m1 package. Edited /etc/default/grub to default to the top kernel (0) and rebuilt the grub config.

Everything has been working, except when `yum update` runs it will update the 3.10.xxx kernel if available and replaces 4.17.xxx in the boot order.

What is the correct way to deal with this issue? Should I add an exclude to the CentOS-Base repository for kernel packages?

Comment: What is set for `GRUB_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`? If it is set to saved then you need to look at grub2 config. Check the value in `/boot/grub2/grubenv`.

Comment: I set it to 0 when I installed the new kernel. The problem is when a new kernel installs whether it be 3.10.xxx or 4.17.xxx the newest install becomes 0. A possible solution I found is to exclude kernel updates in the CentOS repos, but I can't figure out which repo kernel 3.10.xxx is coming from.

Comment: Simply _removing_ the `kernel` package should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I add an exclude to the CentOS-Base repository for kernel packages?

You may `exclude=kernel`. Note that `exclude` is a global variable, in yum.conf and not any of the repos.  This works because [the newer kernel package is intentionally named something different, kernel-ml ("mainline").](http://elrepo.org/tiki/kernel-ml)

The yum versionlock plugin might also be used for the purpose of stopping updates to a given package.

The repo name is the 3rd piece of `yum list` output:

```
kernel.x86_64                    3.10.0-862.6.3.el7                     @updates
$ grep -F [updates] /etc/yum.repos.d/*
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo:[updates]
```

---

Remember that when you replace distro packages with third party ones, you switch maintainers. Ensure you get the security and stability updates you need.

Comment: I did this for security reasons. Redhat's meltdown / Spectre patches were causing lockups with cpservd. The updated kernel resolves those issues.